# Netsuite delete record by button in suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a suitelet in which i am running a html code to show a list of records in a html table format of a custom record type.
I get the list of results from a search for loop.
There i have given a delete button on each line and i want it to delete the record

I want to given button onclick action to delete the records on that line. I even get internal ID of the record

`<td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  onclick="record.delete({ type: "customrecord200",id: '+internalid+', }); "> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> </button> </td>`

Answer (score 0):

Basically to delete record in NetSuite you need to use `N/record` module as follows,

```
record.delete({ type: RECORD_TYPE, id: RECORD_ID });
```

As you mentioned you are using *Suitelet* to show list of records with button on it to delete the records. So you need to attach *Client Script* from your *Suitelet* like

```
form.clientScriptModulePath = 'CLIENT_SCRIPT_PATH'
```

and pass **recordId**(and **recordType** too preferably) to it on button click method which would then use above sample to delete passed record.

Comment: how can i pass functionName to delete button which will then be called in client script?

Comment: In client script expose/return the function that you want to use as **onClick** function. Check [this](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4337761696.html) out for further reading.

Comment: there is no "onClick" in netsuite as far as i can tell...and js onClick claims that there is no function of that name (the one created on the client script side)...